# Xamarin.forms app crashes on iOS with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I've Xamarin.forms app which runs fine on android but on iOS only on one page it get crashed with following error:

```
Incident Identifier: 2305BEB3-026F-4E95-8C4A-DC0CE34CB938
CrashReporter Key:   f542235459b8f45c97f74ec3eebf9a8f0a5f1d12
Hardware Model:      iPhone10,1
Process:             MyAppiOS [655]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EC9826E7-629F-4DD3-92FA-E484ABB25B6F/MyAppiOS.app/MyAppiOS
Identifier:          com.company.myappios
Version:             1.0 (2.48)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.company.myappios [577]


Date/Time:           2018-07-24 10:58:04.2018 -0500
Launch Time:         2018-07-24 10:56:01.4088 -0500
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.4.1 (15G77)
Baseband Version:    1.93.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
VM Region Info: 0 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4309712896
      REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                 0000000100e10000-0000000100e14000 [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...p/MyAppiOS

Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x18179ad8c __exceptionPreprocess + 228 (NSException.m:166)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1809545ec objc_exception_throw + 56 (objc-exception.mm:521)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x18179a9f0 -[NSException raise] + 12 (NSException.m:98)
3   MyAppiOS                    0x102de8d48 wrapper_managed_to_native_Xamarin_ObjCRuntime_Messaging_void_objc_msgSend_intptr_intptr + 33393992 (/<unknown>:1)
4   MyAppiOS                    0x102dec514 HockeySDK_iOSBindings_HockeyApp_iOS_BITHockeyManager_ConvertToNsExceptionAndAbort_object + 367
5   MyAppiOS                    0x102ded6c8 HockeySDK_iOSBindings_HockeyApp_iOS_BITHockeyManager__StartManagerb__9_0_object_System_UnhandledExceptionEventArgs + 19
6   MyAppiOS                    0x1019b5c30 mscorlib_wrapper_delegate_invoke__Module_invoke_void_object_UnhandledExceptionEventArgs_object_System_UnhandledExceptionEventArgs + 119
7   MyAppiOS                    0x10177a018 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 247
8   MyAppiOS                    0x1034f65f8 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 40789496 (mini-runtime.c:2782)
9   MyAppiOS                    0x1035753c0 mono_runtime_try_invoke + 41309120 (object.c:2887)
10  MyAppiOS                    0x10357a228 call_unhandled_exception_delegate + 41329192 (object.c:4554)
11  MyAppiOS                    0x103579d9c mono_unhandled_exception_checked + 41328028 (object.c:4677)
12  MyAppiOS                    0x103579c20 mono_unhandled_exception + 41327648 (object.c:4620)
13  MyAppiOS                    0x1034e5de4 mono_handle_exception_internal + 40721892 (mini-exceptions.c:2027)
14  MyAppiOS                    0x1034e520c mono_handle_exception + 40718860 (mini-exceptions.c:2371)
15  MyAppiOS                    0x1034dca48 mono_arm_throw_exception + 40684104 (exceptions-arm64.c:412)
16  MyAppiOS                    0x10179dc18 throw_exception + 167
17  MyAppiOS                    0x10193f3fc mscorlib_System_Runtime_CompilerServices_AsyncMethodBuilderCore__c__ThrowAsyncb__6_0_object + 11727868 (AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1018)
18  MyAppiOS                    0x1022c2bfc Xamarin_iOS_UIKit_UIKitSynchronizationContext__c__DisplayClass1_0__Postb__0 + 21703676 (UIKitSynchronizationContext.cs:1)
19  MyAppiOS                    0x1022ebe44 Xamarin_iOS_Foundation_NSAsyncActionDispatcher_Apply + 21872196 (NSAction.cs:125)
20  MyAppiOS                    0x10177a018 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 247
21  MyAppiOS                    0x1034f65f8 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 40789496 (mini-runtime.c:2782)
22  MyAppiOS                    0x103573ab0 mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 41302704 (object.c:2887)
23  MyAppiOS                    0x1035772cc mono_runtime_invoke + 41317068 (object.c:2941)
24  MyAppiOS                    0x101619724 native_to_managed_trampoline_5(objc_object*, objc_selector*, _MonoMethod**, unsigned int) + 8427300 (registrar.m:198)
25  MyAppiOS                    0x10161a84c -[__MonoMac_NSAsyncActionDispatcher xamarinApplySelector] + 8431692 (registrar.m:12002)
26  Foundation                      0x1821e60ec __NSThreadPerformPerform + 340 (NSThread.m:1265)
27  CoreFoundation                  0x181743404 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24 (CFRunLoop.c:1982)
28  CoreFoundation                  0x181742c2c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 276 (CFRunLoop.c:2017)
29  CoreFoundation                  0x18174079c __CFRunLoopRun + 1204 (CFRunLoop.c:2920)
30  CoreFoundation                  0x181660da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552 (CFRunLoop.c:3245)
31  GraphicsServices                0x183646020 GSEventRunModal + 100 (GSEvent.c:2245)
32  UIKit                           0x18b680758 UIApplicationMain + 236 (UIApplication.m:3965)
33  MyAppiOS                    0x102258200 wrapper_managed_to_native_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string___intptr_intptr + 367
34  MyAppiOS                    0x1022b9e7c Xamarin_iOS_UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___string_string + 21667452 (UIApplication.cs:63)
35  MyAppiOS                    0x10166ed28 MyAppiOS_AgriSync_Ios_Application_Main_string__ + 27
36  MyAppiOS                    0x10177a018 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 247
37  MyAppiOS                    0x1034f65f8 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 40789496 (mini-runtime.c:2782)
38  MyAppiOS                    0x103573ab0 mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 41302704 (object.c:2887)
39  MyAppiOS                    0x103579828 mono_runtime_exec_main_checked + 41326632 (object.c:4784)
40  MyAppiOS                    0x1034d90b8 mono_jit_exec + 40669368 (driver.g.c:1210)
41  MyAppiOS                    0x10363d468 xamarin_main + 42128488 (monotouch-main.m:485)
42  MyAppiOS                    0x1016552e8 main + 8671976 (main.m:274)
43  libdyld.dylib                   0x1810f1fc0 start + 4

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001812212e0 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001813c66a8 pthread_kill$VARIANT$armv81 + 360 (pthread.c:1484)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018118fd0c abort + 140 (abort.c:91)
3   MyAppiOS                    0x00000001031d87cc -[BITPLCrashReporter generateLiveReportWithThread:] + 0
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018179b1c8 __handleUncaughtException + 828 (NSException.m:219)
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001809548c8 _objc_terminate() + 112 (objc-exception.mm:656)
6   MyAppiOS                    0x00000001031c0418 BITCrashUncaughtCXXTerminateHandler() + 37422104 (BITCrashCXXExceptionHandler.mm:188)
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018094537c std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16 (cxa_handlers.cpp:66)
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000180944ccc __cxa_throw + 132 (cxa_exception.cpp:130)
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000180954720 objc_exception_throw + 364 (objc-exception.mm:547)
10  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018179a9f0 -[NSException raise] + 12 (NSException.m:98)
11  MyAppiOS                    0x0000000102de8d48 wrapper_managed_to_native_Xamarin_ObjCRuntime_Messaging_void_objc_msgSend_intptr_intptr + 33393992 (/<unknown>:1)
12  MyAppiOS                    0x0000000102dec514 HockeySDK_iOSBindings_HockeyApp_iOS_BITHockeyManager_ConvertToNsExceptionAndAbort_object + 368
13  MyAppiOS                    0x0000000102ded6c8 HockeySDK_iOSBindings_HockeyApp_iOS_BITHockeyManager__StartManagerb__9_0_object_System_UnhandledExceptionEventArgs + 20
14  MyAppiOS                    0x00000001019b5c30 mscorlib_wrapper_delegate_invoke__Module_invoke_void_object_UnhandledExceptionEventArgs_object_System_UnhandledExceptionEventArgs + 120
15  MyAppiOS                    0x000000010177a018 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 248
16  MyAppiOS                    0x00000001034f65f8 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 40789496 (mini-runtime.c:2783)
17  MyAppiOS                    0x00000001035753c0 mono_runtime_try_invoke + 41309120 (object.c:2887)
18  MyAppiOS                    0x000000010357a228 call_unhandled_exception_delegate + 41329192 (object.c:4555)
19  MyAppiOS                    0x0000000103579d9c mono_unhandled_exception_checked + 41328028 (object.c:4678)
20  MyAppiOS                    0x0000000103579c20 mono_unhandled_exception + 41327648 (object.c:4621)
21  MyAppiOS                    0x00000001034e5de4 mono_handle_exception_internal + 40721892 (mini-exceptions.c:2053)
22  MyAppiOS                    0x00000001034e520c mono_handle_exception + 40718860 (mini-exceptions.c:2371)
23  MyAppiOS                    0x00000001034dca48 mono_arm_throw_exception + 40684104 (exceptions-arm64.c:414)
24  MyAppiOS                    0x000000010179dc18 throw_exception + 168
25  MyAppiOS                    0x000000010193f3fc mscorlib_System_Runtime_CompilerServices_AsyncMethodBuilderCore__c__ThrowAsyncb__6_0_object + 11727868 (exceptionservicescommon.cs:152)
26  MyAppiOS                    0x00000001022c2bfc Xamarin_iOS_UIKit_UIKitSynchronizationContext__c__DisplayClass1_0__Postb__0 + 21703676 (UIKitSynchronizationContext.cs:1)
27  MyAppiOS                    0x00000001022ebe44 Xamarin_iOS_Foundation_NSAsyncActionDispatcher_Apply + 21872196 (NSAction.cs:126)
28  MyAppiOS                    0x000000010177a018 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 248
29  MyAppiOS                    0x00000001034f65f8 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 40789496 (mini-runtime.c:2783)
30  MyAppiOS                    0x0000000103573ab0 mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 41302704 (object.c:2887)
31  MyAppiOS                    0x00000001035772cc mono_runtime_invoke + 41317068 (object.c:2941)
32  MyAppiOS                    0x0000000101619724 native_to_managed_trampoline_5(objc_object*, objc_selector*, _MonoMethod**, unsigned int) + 8427300 (registrar.m:198)
33  MyAppiOS                    0x000000010161a84c -[__MonoMac_NSAsyncActionDispatcher xamarinApplySelector] + 8431692 (registrar.m:12003)
34  Foundation                      0x00000001821e60ec __NSThreadPerformPerform + 340 (NSThread.m:1265)
35  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181743404 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24 (CFRunLoop.c:1982)
36  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181742c2c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 276 (CFRunLoop.c:2017)
37  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018174079c __CFRunLoopRun + 1204 (CFRunLoop.c:2920)
38  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181660da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552 (CFRunLoop.c:3245)
39  GraphicsServices                0x0000000183646020 GSEventRunModal + 100 (GSEvent.c:2245)
40  UIKit                           0x000000018b680758 UIApplicationMain + 236 (UIApplication.m:3965)
41  MyAppiOS                    0x0000000102258200 wrapper_managed_to_native_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string___intptr_intptr + 368
42  MyAppiOS                    0x00000001022b9e7c Xamarin_iOS_UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___string_string + 21667452 (UIApplication.cs:64)
43  MyAppiOS                    0x000000010166ed28 MyAppiOS_AgriSync_Ios_Application_Main_string__ + 28
44  MyAppiOS                    0x000000010177a018 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 248
45  MyAppiOS                    0x00000001034f65f8 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 40789496 (mini-runtime.c:2783)
46  MyAppiOS                    0x0000000103573ab0 mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 41302704 (object.c:2887)
47  MyAppiOS                    0x0000000103579828 mono_runtime_exec_main_checked + 41326632 (object.c:0)
48  MyAppiOS                    0x00000001034d90b8 mono_jit_exec + 40669368 (driver.g.c:1210)
49  MyAppiOS                    0x000000010363d468 xamarin_main + 42128488 (monotouch-main.m:0)
50  MyAppiOS                    0x00000001016552e8 main + 8671976 (main.m:274)
51  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001810f1fc0 start + 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Bad access sounds like the app has not the right to do something. Maybe the android app has it. You can set the rights for the app in the ios project settings.